# Mocking a class having @Configuration annotation

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

My spring class have annotation @Configuration. I want to mock it using Mockito in JUnits but unable to do so.
Example class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="abc.filter")
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class ConfigProp {  
    public String enabled=false;
}
```

The way I am trying to mock it is:

`@Mock private ConfigProp configProp;`

and

```
ConfigProp prop=mock(ConfigProp.class)
```

But none of them work.
Please suggest how can I mock this class.

Comment: Could you show the code of your test class? Without it it's hard to tell how you're running your tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem, so common, I developed a JUnit test extension to solve the problem: https://github.com/exabrial/mockito-object-injection

My test extension allows you to set a `@InjectSource` field to set String values (or any other object) during testing, without resorting to reflection API. For example:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
 @Value("securityEnabled")
 private Boolean securityEnabled;
 @Autowired
 private Authenticator auther;
 @Autowired
 private Logger log;

 public void doSomething() {
  if (securityEnabled) {
    auther.something();
  } else {
    log.warn("sec disabled");
  }
 }
}


@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith({ MockitoExtension.class, InjectExtension.class })
class MyControllerTest {
 @InjectMocks
 private MyController myController;
 @Mock
 private Logger log;
 @Mock
 private Authenticator auther;
 @InjectionSource
 private Boolean securityEnabled;
 
 @Test
 void testDoSomething_secEnabled() throws Exception {
  securityEnabled = Boolean.TRUE;
  myController.doSomething();
  // wahoo no NPE! Test the "if then" half of the branch
 }
 
 @Test 
 void testDoSomething_secDisabled() throws Exception {
  securityEnabled = Boolean.FALSE;
  myController.doSomething();
  // wahoo no NPE! Test the "if else" half of branch
 }
}
```